# Get error "firestore is not a function" when upgrade an old Firebase from 5.4.0 to 5.5.x

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got a "**firestore is not a function**" error after I had updated my code by "npm i firestore@latest"

I have tried to clear my node_modules out and re-install a project, But the issue still the same.  How can I resolve this issue? Is this a bug?

Below is my import code:

```
var firebase = require('firebase/app');
require("firebase/firestore");

var fbApp = firebase.initializeApp({...});
var db = fbApp.firestore();
```